# @$_POST['something']; and $_POST['something'];?

Tags: php, ajax, post, wamp

I have a simple js script in my file named **index.php**:

```
$.ajax({
    type:  "POST",
    data:  'a='+hi+'&b='+hello,
    url:   "update.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
        console.log('Ajax success');
    },
    error: function() {
        console.error('Ajax error');
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log('Ajax complete');
    }
});
```

In I look in my console, I have my 2 messages: success and complete.

The 2 vars *a* and *b* contains some stuff. I want to send these datas in a file named **update.php** wich contains:

```
$a = @$_POST['hi'];
$b = @$_POST['hello'];
```

In my update.php file, if I do a `echo $a;`, it didn't work (nothing appears). If I do a `var_dump($_POST);`, it returns:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

These 2 files works fine on my webserver but nothing works on my local workflow with wamp.

I'm not sure about my `$a = @$_POST['hi'];`. I tryed with `$a = $_POST['hi'];` but it returns: `Undefined index: hi` (same thing for "hello").

That means $a and $b are NULL but in my **index.php** file, the 2 vars contains my stuff.

Any idea bout how to solve this problem?
Thx in advance.

Comment: What are the values of `hi` and `hello`?

Comment: When you look in your console, there should be a network tab that shows the POST request to update.php. Look at the POST data sent there to verify you are actually sending the data you think you are. From the echoes you've shown it appears no POST data is being sent. The `@` is simply an error silencer - don't use it unless you know what you are doing. Errors are good, they tell you what is wrong, which, in your case, is that the $_POST array contains no information - including the 'hi' index you are looking for.

Comment: It is also worth noting that you are trying to send `a=something&b=something` and then you are checking the `$_POST` variable for `$_POST['hi']` and `$_POST['hello']` when you should be checking for `$_POST['a']` and `$_POST['b']` given the query string you are trying to send.

Comment: @SarahKemp That's true, but it doesn't explain why `var_dump()` says there are no post parameters at all.

Comment: `hi` is `hi` and `hello` is `hello` (strings). I checked in my "network" tab. The POST status in 200 (ok). My datas are sent.

Comment: Then it sounds like the problem is somewhere in your PHP script. It may be overwriting `$_POST`.

Comment: Currently, the full php file is:

<?php
    $a = $_POST['hi'];
    $b = $_POST['hello'];

    //var_dump($_POST); (now commented)
    
    echo $a;
    echo $b;
?>

Hum sorry for the inline code. I failed with markdown

Answer (score 3):

`@` suppresses the error. That doesn't make it magically work. You still get the 'undefined index' error, but it doesn't show anymore.

I think the problem is in the way you pass the data. Try passing it as an object:

```
$.ajax({
    type:  "POST",
    data:  { 
       a: hi,  /* 'a' is the key, 'hi' is the value. */
       b: hello },
    url:   "update.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
        console.log('Ajax success');
    },
    error: function() {
        console.error('Ajax error');
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log('Ajax complete');
    }
});
```

Apart from using `var_dump($_POST);` in PHP to dump the entire contents of the posted information, you can also use the developer tools in your browser (usually under F12) to inspect the posted request.

If you use these debugging tools, then you will probably notice that you post the keys 'a' and 'b', while reading the keys 'hi' and 'hello', which is probably the cause of your error.

Barmar is right in his comment that your method should work fine as well, although the object notation is more convenient, because it will escape special characters for you and I think it's a bit more readable.

Comment: This is why I asked for the values of the variables before posting an answer. Unless they contain some special characters that require encoding, his method should work.

Comment: Your "future debugging" describes something he already did. The question shows the output of `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: The method he already using , the same just other way , no any difference

Comment: Did you change the keys? Your (and my) code are posting values with key 'a' and 'b'. You are reading key 'hi'. Make sure to read `$_POST['a']` in your PHP script.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Same error with `$_POST['a']`. Still Undefined.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't use `@` at development.

I made you a working example using JSON type:

**HTML (Index.php):**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>new</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="editplus" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#click').bind('click', test);

   });

  function test(){

      var hi = 'hi';
      var hello = 'hello';

      var dataString = 'a='+ hi + '&b='+ hello;

         $.ajax({  
              url: "update.php",
              type: "POST",  
              data: dataString,
              dataType:'json',
              cache: false,
              success: function(data)
              {     
                $('div').html(data.succ+' ,a = '+data.a + ', B = ' + data.b+ ' , '+data.time);  
              }
        });  
  return false;
}
  </script>

 </head>

 <body>

  <input type="submit" id="click" value="Click">

<div></div>

 </body >
</html>
```

**update.php:**

```
 <?php

  $a = $_POST['a'];
  $b = $_POST['b'];

  $return = array('succ' => 'true','a' => $a,'b' => $b,'time' => time());
  header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
  echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

As you can see i take POSTS a & b to the update.php file and return the results to index.php.

Working perfect.

**EDIT:**

I also tested the current code you gave , it's working too :

[image]

You can see response A and B at network tab.

I just changed at update.php to:

```
 <?php

    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];

    echo 'a='.$a;
    echo ',';
    echo 'b='.$b;

?>
```

Comment: Yep that's what I said, it's a mistake but the result is the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964336/postsomething-and-postsomething#comment36920996_23964374

Comment: Hum yep my method isn't very "clean" but the result should be the same.
In fact, in the update.php, normally I have all my sql stuff and the ajax send the datas in my database. It don't work, that's why I created this thread without the sql stuff because the problem isn't the database but something in the update.php file. I have the same things in my "network" tab. All my datas are here.

Btw I tryed your files: same problem. It didn't work. I think the problem is with Wamp :/

Comment: Still not clear. The issue you mentioned is about you'r A and B not being sent to update.php. i have answered about the QUESTION issue, you should open new question about you'r real problem and add there ALL the update.php file, it's not the ajax problem and not the current update.php file.

Comment: Ok I understand. Your code works on my webserver but not in my local workflow.
The problem is probably Wamp. I'll open a new question. Thx for your answers and tips :)

Comment: You'r welcome, better tick answered so the system won't block you from post more questions. read rules, good luck. will try to help you at the specific problem, try reinstall wamp before.